# How to create an error report and Log that contains information from all libraries using .Net Framework (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, error-handling, report

I am about to create some library that contains all common functions I used in my projects. (Opening File Dialogs, reading spreadsheets, etc..)
And I am planning to use it when I develop some Form application. All my classes are static in that library project.
Here is a example scenario:
I wrote `Library.dll` and add it to my `Form` project as reference.  I am always using `Console.Writeline()` to watch what happened in my code. So I did the same in `Library.dll`.Lets say I have `LibraryClass.cs` in my `Library.dll` And when I call a function from that class to Form project I can not see the Console logs inside of that function.

I create another static class at my library called `Report.cs`. It creates 2 different type of lists. First one is a string list, and using instead of `Console.WriteLine()`, I am using this string list. I am using `Report.WriteLine()` function to add strings inside of that string list. It helps me the collect all the logs that I wrote in Form and also in Library.
The second one is a Record object that I created. It contains information like "Code", "Info", "Title" "Reference", "Type" as properties. Type property allows me to define record as an "Error" or "Warning" or just a "Record". If I can catch an error from catch statement or some warning, I am creating an Record object that contains information I mentioned and I am adding it to that Record list in `Report.cs`. But I am pretty sure there is a more efficient way to do that.
Here is my Record Object:

```
     public class ReportElement
     {
        public string Info { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime Time;
        public string Reference { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public List<string> Targets { get; set; }
        public string Log { get; }
        public ReportElementType Type { get; set; }

        public ReportElement(string code, string info, string title, ReportElementType reportElementType = ReportElementType.kJournal, string reference = null, List<string> targets = null)
        {
            this.Info = info;
            this.Title = title;
            this.Time = DateTime.Now;
            this.Code = code;
            this.Type = reportElementType;
            this.Targets = targets;
            this.Reference = reference;
            this.Log = this.CreateLogString();
            Report.WriteLine(this.Log);
        }

        public enum ReportElementType
        {
            kError = 0,
            kWarning = 1,
            kJournal = 2
        }
    }
```

And I am collecting that elements in my Report Class inside of a List:

```
private static List<ReportElement> RecordedReportElements = new List<ReportElement>();
```

List of logs(Also in report class:

```
public static List<string> ListLog = new List<string>();
```

And I am writing strings in that list with that function:

```
 public static void WriteLine(string Text, bool WithTimer = true)
        {
            try
            {
                string logString = WithTimer? Text + " | " + GetTimerValue():Text;
                ListLog.Add(logString);
                Console.WriteLine(logString);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Can not be saved in List Log : " + Text);
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

At the end I can use this library in any other project like this:

```
Report.WriteLine("MY LOG STRING")
ReportElement NewElement = new ReportElement(Code, Info, Title, ReportElementType, Reference, Targets);
Report.RecordedReportElements.Add(NewELement)
```

So the summary of the things I need to achieve:

1. Creating an journal mechanic ( The list that contains all the record object that i created.)
2. Collect all console logs from the library I used and form application I am developing.
3. If some error happens at my library, my library also have to be able to terminate my form application.
4. After termination I want to be able to make some report visible.(as .txt or .xlsx or as an another form)

So at the end anyone has better strategy to do that or some documentation that explains how to catch errors, and create a report after the process done or terminate.
Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Codes are provided. @Community